# Pretty-printing with JSON Spirit

Tags: c++, json, json-spirit

My C++ program receives a long (thousands of symbols) JSON string, which I'd like to print using JSON Spirit (for debugging) with multiple lines, right indentation etc. For example:

```
{
  "abc": "def",
  "xyz":
  [
    "pqr": "ijk"
  ]
}
```

and so on. I tried the `write` function:

```
const json_spirit::Value val("...long JSON string here ...");
cout << json_spirit::write(val, json_spirit::pretty_print) << endl;
```

but got only additional backslashes in the original string.

Can you please advise how to do that?

Comment: On line 230 in the [writer_template.h](https://sirikata.github.io/json-spirit/writer__template_8h_source.html) file the function `add_escape_chars` is called when a string is being output. As far as I can see, there's no way to prevent this from happening without messing with the code.

Comment: See line 56 of [writer_template.h](https://sirikata.github.io/json-spirit/writer__template_8h_source.html), where `"` is explicitly escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting your original input string back is because you assign the string directly to a `json_spirit::Value`. What you need to do instead is have `json_spirit` parse the string.

The C++11 code below gives the expected output:

```
#include <json_spirit/json_spirit.h>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string const inputStr = 
    R"raw({ "abc": "def", "xyz": [ "pqr": "ijk" ] })raw";

  json_spirit::Value inputParsed;
  json_spirit::read(inputStr, inputParsed);

  std::cout 
    << json_spirit::write(inputParsed, json_spirit::pretty_print) << "\n";
}
```

*Side note:* There's a whole bunch of more lightweight C++ JSON libraries  (i.e. not requiring Boost), in case that should interest you. I've personally used [nlohmann's json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) which requires only a single header file. [RapidJSON](https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson) seems to be an excellent option as well. Tons of benchmarks for 40+ C++ JSON libraries can be found on the [nativejson-benchmark](https://github.com/miloyip/nativejson-benchmark) page.

Comment: @HEKTO Done, see completely overhauled answer.